# Capture Image with android camera along overlays

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I have created an application which contains different images, which I can place over the android camera. Then there is a button to capture the image, but the issue is it will only capture the camera view and overlays are not handled. Is there any simple way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

load the captured image as a bitmap and draw the overlay stuff on the bitmap. 
Save the bitmap.

Comment: thanks but this is not a problem. i need to place images on real time and them capture image.

Comment: When you save the camera image you save it as a bitmap right? before saving why dont' you try drawing the overlay onto it?